# How to update Actor after applying Transformation?

Tags: vtk

Currently I apply translation to an actor through below code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> translation =
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
translation->PostMultiply(); //this is the key line
translation->Translate(translationVector);
patella->getActor()->SetUserTransform(translation);
```

However, if I apply

```
patella->getActor()->SetUserTransform(translation);
```

again. The actor stays at the same position as if I applied it only once. I know it's because the origin is not updated. Thus, how can I update the origin/actor after each translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to concatenate the transforms. Something like:

```
vtkActor* patellaActor = patella->GetActor();
vtkTransform* patellaXfm = patellaActor->GetUserTransform();
if (!patellaXfm) {
    patellaActor->SetUserTransform(translation);
} else {
    patellaXfm->Concatenate(translation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I did is manually multiply the transformation matrix with the points of the polydata.

Comment: Visually it ends up being the same, but there are two important consequences: you are modifying the actual data, and it's much more computationally expensive.  If you really want to modify the data, use vtkTransformPolyDataFilter instead of manual multiplication.

Comment: @mimi That's another problem. For `vtkTransformPolyDataFilter,` somehow I can only provide `reader0>GetOutputPort()` since my `mapper->GetOutputPort()` is always `null`. I believe if I provide the reader object then the 3D object will move only once.

Comment: That moment when you google intensly an issue,find VTK doc, VTK userlist and even go to the 2nd page of google, and find the answer on good old SO. Thanks mate !

Comment: @Soltius Glad it was helpful!